# Reading back pandas dataframe saved with pyarrow gives wrong values

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

I was trying to save a pandas dataframe to parquet format using Pyarrow v2, and I ran into a weird problem. The (simplified) dataframe has one string column and one nested column (list of dicts). Here is an example:

```
labels = ["aa", 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']
vals = [random.choice(labels) for _ in range(2000)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'names': vals})
df["name_nested"] = df.names.apply(lambda x: [{"label": x}])
df.to_parquet("x.par")
```

as you see the columns "names" and "name_nested" should have the same values:

df.head()

```
    names   name_nested
0   bb  [{'label': 'bb'}]
1   aa  [{'label': 'aa'}]
2   cc  [{'label': 'cc'}]
3   cc  [{'label': 'cc'}]
4   cc  [{'label': 'cc'}]
```

However, once I reload from disk the saved parquet file, things are weird, I don't get same result:

```
df2 = pd.read_parquet("x.par")
df2["name_nested2"] = df2.name_nested.apply(lambda x: x[0]["label"])

len(df2[df2.name_nested2 != df2.names])

# 726
```

Out of the 2000 entries, there are 726 entries which do not match. here is an example:

```
df2[df2.name_nested2 != df2.names] 

    names   name_nested name_nested2
1025    dd  [{'label': 'cc'}]   cc
1027    bb  [{'label': 'aa'}]   aa
1029    aa  [{'label': 'cc'}]   cc
1031    dd  [{'label': 'aa'}]   aa
1035    bb  [{'label': 'dd'}]   dd
```

As you see the column `name_nested` is not the same as `names` anymore! This is very wrong behavior. also I noticed that this happens only if the dataframe has more than 1024 rows, and the mismatches happen only after row 1024 too.

I thought this would be a known issue, but couldn't find any information about this.

Once I upgraded to Pyarrow 6, this is no longer an issue, but wanted to understand the root cause of this, if anyone have seen this before.

Comment: Yikes! That's pretty horrifying.

Answer (score 1):

PyArrow version 2.0.0 is pretty old, and many improvements have happened on the parquet support since then. Consider PyArrow is currently at version 8.0.0. I suggest you upgrade to the latest version to benefit from all the recent work.

Your specific issue might be related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-11607 which was addressed in version 4.0.0